# Create a list like draggable menu

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7.
I would like to create a list of items in which all items can be arranged using Drag 'n' Drop. Just like Menu system in Drupal.

I found [drupal_add_tabledrag()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7) but it seems it is used in table display/output. I want to create a simple list with rows and it should be arranged, just like menu in Drupal7.

Though there is [DragableView](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module, but I want that every logged in users can create a list and they can manage their own list.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [Node Queue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue)?
It could be useful for you:

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily
>   ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 comes with jquery UI library. You can use them to achieve above functionality with small snipped of jquery code.

Check [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) and [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) documentations. [This](http://www.slideshare.net/darrenmothersele/jquery-ui-widgets-drag-and-drop-drupal-7-javascript) will surely help you.